# What does "all-or-nothing" means in spiking neural network?

Tags: neuroscience, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm reading a paper by [Auge et al. (2021)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11063-021-10562-2). In the introduction they said "Spiking Neural Networks (SNNs) use short 'all-or-nothing' pulses to encode and transmit information".

I'm not sure what is the meaning of "all-or-nothing" in this context.
Does it mean binary?

Auge, D., Hille, J., Mueller, E., & Knoll, A. (2021). [A survey of encoding techniques for signal processing in spiking neural networks.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11063-021-10562-2) Neural Processing Letters, 53(6), 4693-4710.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an artificial network, yes, it typically means there is a binary **output**; this is a standard neuron model.

For a biological network, it's a bit more complicated, because although any moment in time can be a "spike" or "no spike", there isn't some discrete timeseries described by a binary code, but rather single events with an occurrence time.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it comes from physiology where the strength of the response of a neuron or muscle fiber doesn't have anything to do with the strength of the stimulus. If a stimulus is above a certain threshold, the neuron will fire. So, in terms of SNN, it seems to me like a binary coding, where a neuron is either active or inactive within a specific time interval.